# Merge tag [geographical-information] into [gis]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are currently two tags:

- [gis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gis) (3,057 questions)
- [geographical-information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geographical-information) (86 questions)

GIS generally stands for [Geographic Information System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) but can also be used for Geographic Information Science and Geographic Information Software.

No matter what the three letter acronym is expanded to, I think that tag [geographical-information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geographical-information) should be made a synonym of, and then be merged into tag [gis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gis).

Incidentally, there is a large and mature [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) with 78,748 questions, where questions tagged [gis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gis) would reach a broader community of GIS specialists.

Comment: Good idea, I tried too https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372195/merge-tags-geospatial-spatial-gis