# Merge tags: [geospatial], [spatial], [gis]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I can't see any reason to keep these tags separate.

- [geospatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geospatial)
- [geography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geography)
- [spatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spatial)
- [gis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gis)
- [geographical-information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geographical-information)

On DBA.SE, they're all mapped to `[spatial]`. That would be my suggestion here. But, if someone wants to keep them separate, perhaps we could make the tagging exclusive and well defined in the wiki so people will know when to use which.

I'm in the industry. `geo-` traditionally meant Earth which would exclude Mars. That's the only distinction I know of even in theory. And, no one follows that distinction today (that I know of).

Comment: Sure, or [tag:geography] which is essentially again the same thing, except there may be a few that are tagging that only because the data set is talking about countries and the like, but that would be the exception look at it.

Comment: I don't think "spatial" and "gis" belong to the same topics. Spatial is (in contrast to gis) used in the CG and geometry processing community for, well, spatial data structures (like octrees, spatial hashing, etc.). But this data has nothing to do with geo data or geography. [tag:geometry] should imho be removed. It doesn't describe a concept that would be on-topic here.

Comment: It's a good argument. Would you object into merging GIS into spatial? Do you view GIS as a subset of Spatial or as something that's mutually exclusive?

Comment: I'd say all gis questions are about spatial data, but not all spatial questions are about gis. I wouldn't merge them in any direction. Merging [tag:geospatial], [tag:geography], [tag:gis] and [tag:geographical-information] sounds like a good plane to me.

Comment: I think that would be a **huge** step in the right direction. Would you suggest them disambiguating GIS and spatial? Or do you think GIS questions should all have the spatial tag too?

Comment: Good question. We should most probably ask the gis community what they want. I'm from the CG side.

Comment: Is this a synonym request? Please add [synonym-request] tag then.